# JQuery Ajax executing php script with predefined id

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery/AJAX to run a PHP script that do a delete query of table in database using predefined id. Here's the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#clear").click(function(){
   $.post("action.php?module=cart&act=del&id=$_GET[id]");
});
});
</script>
```

And the action.php code is:

```
if ($module=='cart' AND $act=='del'){
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM orders_temp WHERE id_pro='$_GET[id]'")
  header('Location:list.php?id=$_GET[id]');        
}
```

But it not work. How to make it work?

Comment: are you sure about this? `$.post("action.php?module=cart&act=del&id=$_GET[id]");`

Comment: Also, be REEEAAAALLLYYYY careful with that query.  You need to escape the user input, or ideally use prepared statements.  Otherwise you might have something like this!  http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

First, the user Ghost pointed correctly, look to your function $.post, you are mixing post with get.

If you want send id parameter by get (url) then try something like this (i don't tested this code but if you understand and solve your question i can improve this answer):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#clear").click(function(){
            var id = 2;//put here the id, may be via jquery for example
            var url = "action.php?module=cart&act=del&id="+id;

            $.ajax({                 
                type: 'GET',                               
                url: url,                                 
                data: dados,                 
                success: function(response) {
                    //here you decides if you want make something with response 
                }             
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In your php file you get the parameter and do what you want:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
if ($module=='cart' AND $act=='del'){
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM orders_temp WHERE id_pro='".$id."'");
  header('Location:list.php?id='.$id);        
}
```

P.S.: Remember that you needs verify input from users, implement, prepared statements, use of issets in php variables and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. You are mixing PHP syntax with JavaScript syntax here:

   ```
   $.post("action.php?module=cart&act=del&id=$_GET[id]");
   ```

If you view the source of this page, you will find that the end of this line has not been parsed into anything useful.

2. As other users have pointed out, you are sending this request via POST, not GET, but you are passing this parameter in a querystring so it should still be there.But, because of the problem above, you will find that $id does not contain the ID, but a string containing "$_GET[id]". However, since you don't appear to be POSTing any parameters, better to just send this as a GET in my opinion.

I assume you want something like this:

```
$.get("action.php?module=cart&act=del&id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>");
```

That way, assuming that the page on which this is being run is being parsed as PHP and assuming that id is being set to something in the querystring, that value will be parsed and added into the JavaScript.

Good luck!